# Access table without using schema name

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

In oracle, i have a userA and userB, I am unable to access table under userA from userB. It can only be accessed using userB.table
I read all the threads and found a synonym and alter session can only fix my problem.
Just wanted to understand is there any other way apart from using synonym and alter session????

Comment: What is the problem, with those two ways ? Another way is to create all tables in a common schema, and give access to both users to that schema via roles.

Comment: Hi sudipta, i must have mentioned the reason....i have 2 environments...in one environment i am able to access the table from userB without schema and without alter  session, whereas my other environment is not working as per the env1....so i am unable to identify what could be the other way apart from the mentioned 2...

Comment: I don't understand. If in your "good" environment you are able to access `userB.table` (while logged in as `userA`) by just typing `table` (without the schema name), this means that you already have a synonym defined on that table in the "good" environment. Why would you not want to implement the same solution in the "other" environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same query when you login both as user A and user B simply write in both cases the query as:

```
SELECT * from userB.table
```

Synonyms are usually a good idea, be careful to use alter session expecially if in the same query you join with other table of user A